# Cannot access Firebase old project

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I have been provided access to a Firebase project that was created and still maintained on old console by the project owner.

When I try logging into Firebase new console, I cannot see those projects in my account. I also tried logging into an old console specifically, but I automatically get redirected to the new console.

Can anyone help me accessing the old Firebase project to which I have been permitted access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you didn't have an account (or have no more projects) on the legacy Firebase dashboard.

The easiest way to get access to the other project is to have the owner upgrade it to the new console. This is a simple clickthrough process that does not require you to update the code.

Comment: Thanks for a quick help Frank, But asking the owner to upgrade project wouldn't require upgrading the firebase apis used in the code to new version?

Comment: No it wouldn't. See the last line in my answer, the first bullet in the dialog when you upgrade ("Upgrade to the new Firebase SDKs at any time") and [step 3 in the upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#update_your_client_version_numbered) ("You don't have to update the code of your applications right away. Existing database and authentication code will continue to work against your upgraded project.")